# How to improve my answers: understanding the voting and answer acceptance behavior

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

I'd like to get people's thoughts on why [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835615/getting-a-compile-error-in-c-sharp-about-not-referencing-system-xml-yes-system/31835705#31835705) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835615/getting-a-compile-error-in-c-sharp-about-not-referencing-system-xml-yes-system) was not voted as highly as the accepted answer and why it was not accepted instead of the accepted answer.

How could I improve my answers in the future or modify my approach to give better answers?

Note that I posted my original answer 13 seconds after the accepted answer.  I understand the whole "give more credit to the first answer" phenomenon, but I'm not sure that's what's at play here.  Additionally, while that answer did not get changed at all, I went on to respond to comments and make my answer better over the course of the next 20 minutes.  It wasn't until much later that the votes ended up reaching their current totals and the the answer ultimately being accepted.  I'm left wondering if a shorter, more-concise answer is preferred over what I have given.

Comment: The accepted answer is concise, straight-to-the-point. The question indicates that the asker has at least *some* familiarity with the tool at hand  (VS) and he is unlikely to require a "for dummies"-style guide with screen caps. Your answer is very good, the accepted one is just way easier to comprehend and judge

Comment: Them's the rolls. Keep on answering, sometimes it goes one, sometimes the other way. If I got a dime for every post where I lost to someone else getting more votes I'd not be posting here right now. Or maybe I would, but from my yacht.

Comment: You wrote an answer that targeted the OP instead of the broad audience.  The OP can give you only one vote, you get the rest from SO users.  They already know how to tackle a very trite problem like this, they don't need pictures.  You'll have to wait a couple of years to encounter enough Googlers that actually *need* the pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm left wondering if a shorter, more-concise answer is preferred over what I have given.

It depends on the question and the OP.  Sometimes people find shorter, more focused answers are actually more helpful than elaborate, long answers.  There are a few reasons I can think of:

- Shorter answers are easier to understand and verify quickly.  It either works or it doesn't.  In contrast, answers that appear longer take more effort and concentration for people to judge.  A lot of potential upvoters probably stared at your picture like a deer in the headlights and balked at judging the post.
- A lot of times, the OP is really more interested in solving the problem without understanding the inner workings of a solution.  Shorter answers get right to the heart of the error and quickly propose a solution.
- Longer answers might provide *too much* information, which hides the truly useful information.  Readers with some background knowledge have to sift through all the stuff they already know and hunt for the important information.  It's like having to play a tutorial level over and over again for each new game.

Even though you put more effort into your answer, it might have been overkill for this simple resolution.  Regardless, your answer is still good (since it has a positive score).  The other one might have just been more helpful.

Comment: One minor thing: the phrase is "like a deer in the headlights", meaning wide-eyed and full of fear as a car is coming at it from the dark. A deer in the headlines would also probably be frightened, but perhaps more confused than anything else ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan funny, I always associated that idiom with being petrified (to inaction) with surprise.

Comment: @ryanyuyu you're right but that is why the saying is like a deer caught in headlights, because you image being a deer seeing headlights of a car coming right at you, you would be petrified

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I just now realized my typo.  My bad.  We agreed on the same idiom.  I thought I typed "headlights" but I had obviously not.   Updated.

Comment: @ryanyuyu No worries, for a long time I thought the David Bowie song "Eyes Without a Face" was "How's About a Date" :)

Answer (score 5):

Life must go on. You have some Upvotes, not downvoted.

If on One question,your answer is not accepted, then this is not end of life. May be on another question, you can win the race. Move on. And the most important thing, Your answer is very well written and good(you have more explanation, acceptance is totally in OP's hand), this is just a moment, move forward, keep answering, and next moment with you.

The answer you provided have, screenshot, some basics stuff which is not related to this OP question as OP already understand this, but related to broad audience. So this time OP only wants very specific answer, which just give him a clue, how to solve my problem.